# Magento 1.9.3.4 : Change favicon icon

Tags: magento-1.9, image, media, favicons

I want to change favicon icon while access pdf/image file from media path.I actually i already tried to change from admin and also update icon in media and skin folder but favicon icon not changed in media files.Also  tried to change in root directory.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Your favicon is must have the name "favicon.ico" and you must put the file in your current theme, EX.: `skin/frontend/package/theme/favicon.ico`

Comment: But i want to access from media.I can't move it in skin folder.

Answer (score 3):

To change the Favicon simply:

**Frontend:** go `Admin > system > configuration > General > Design tab > HTML Head > Favicon` then you upload your **favicon** with the allowed file types: `ico`, `png`, `gif`, `jpg`, etc...

**Admin:** `skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico`

> NB: don't forget to clear your browser and Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is 5 years too late...

To update your favicon image you have two options:

1. Place the desired `ico` image in your `skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>` directory (as suggested by St3phan above)
2. Upload your `ico` image to the `media/favicon` directory and create a `core_config_data` row with a value pointing towards it.

You can look at `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php` `_getFaviconFile()` to see how the favicon file is loaded. Also note that the Head block will check the media directory first and looks for the file specified in `Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/shortcut_icon')` before it checks the skin directory. Also note that the skin directory version must be named `favicon.ico`.

While there is the `System->Configuration->General->Design->HTML Head->Favicon Icon` field you can supposedly use to update your favicon image, it does not work for `ico` files. This is due to the validation that is run during the save process in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` which calls `imagecreatefromstring` (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) which will always return false because it does not support `ico` files.